# How to wait for an observable to complete before continuing with the next one?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, nestjs, observable, reactive-programming

I'm starting to learn the observables, I have some questions about how to do the following:

1. I have an array of objects.
2. I want to consume an API for each item in the array.
3. For each response I want to combine it into one, as an array of response objects.
4. I am consuming an API that sends messages, so I want when a message is sent, it wait to continue with the next item.

I'm using NestJS (typescript)

I already solved the first 3 items.

My problem is that I am consuming a messaging API, with the code that I made it does not wait for an observable to finish with the response valid and it is already executing the next one, this affects that it sends the messages out of order.

```
 return of(individualMessages).pipe(
      map(messages => messages.map(body =>
        this.sendSingleWhatsappMessage(url, body, config, inputQuery)
         .pipe( map((resp) => resp)))),
      mergeMap(ApiRes => forkJoin(ApiRes)), 
    );
```

for example I have this Array

```
const messages = [ { id: "9r8f", body: "Hello"},{ id: "9r8f", body: "Good morning"}]
```

for each item of the array I want to consume the messages API

the API response is a status code with an id

```
{ statusCode: 200, id="87438fsdfhsd"}
```

I want it to return the response of each consumption combined in an array

```
[{ statusCode: 200, id="87438fsdfhsd"}, { statusCode: 200, id="72448fsd66hsd"}]
```

I did this correctly, my problem is that the Api can take a long time sending a message and when this happens the messages are seen in disorder

example:

1. Good Morning => message 2
2. Hello => message 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original code simplifies to this:

```js
return of(individualMessages).pipe(
    map(messages => messages.map(
        ({body}) => this.sendSingleWhatsappMessage(url, body, config, inputQuery)
    )),
    mergeMap(requests => forkJoin(requests)),
);
```

Behavior:

- `map` transforms your array of `Messages` into an array of requests
- `forkJoin` creates a single observable that will execute all requests at the same time and return an array of the results
- `mergeMap` subscribes to this inner "forkJoin observable" and emits its result (the array of results).

Based on this, I would expect that your array of results ARE in the correct order, but there is a chance that they are not necessarily completed in sequential order (*since they are all dispatched at the same time, order is not guaranteed*).

---

If you want to execute each request in sequence, you could do something like this:

```js
return from(individualMessages).pipe(
    concatMap(({body}) => this.sendSingleWhatsappMessage(url, body, config, inputQuery)),
    toArray()
);
```

Behavior:

- `from` emits each array item indivually
- `concatMap` will subscribe to each request "one at a time" and emit its result
- `toArray()` will collect all received emissions and emit as an array once the source observable completes